# Which quarterback has had the lowest "highest amount of interceptions thrown" during a given regular season?

Tags: american-football, statistics, history, nfl

Ben Roethlisberger led the league during the 2018 NFL season with 16 interceptions. At a glance, that number seems low.

Since the [1970 NFL-AFL merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFL%E2%80%93NFL_merger), which quarterback has had the lowest "highest amount of interceptions thrown" during a given regular season?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Pro Football Reference](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/leaders/pass_int_year_by_year.htm), the lowest "highest amount of interceptions thrown" during a given regular season since the [NFL-AFL merger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFL%E2%80%93NFL_merger) is 16.

Two quarterbacks accomplished this feat:

- Ben Roethlisberger (2018)
- Joe Ferguson ([1982](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Football_League_Players_Association#1982_strike)<sup>†</sup>)

† <sub>- lockout shortened season</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Drew Lock and Carson Wentz threw 15 interceptions during the 2020 season, which is less than the aforementioned 16.

Reference: [Pro-Football-Reference.com](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/leaders/pass_int_year_by_year.htm)

Comment: Your username being Drew Wentz, and the 2 QBs you listed in the answer being DREW Lock and Carson WENTZ can't be a coincident! Welcome to Sports SE Drew Wentz :)